# assigning values to 2d list using for loop in python not working correctly

Tags: python, list, for-loop, 2d, variable-assignment

I want to assign values to list 'a' using for loop. But its not working correctly.
The output of 2nd loop is not same as output of first loop.
It should be same but its not.
Why its not working correctly?

I am running python 3.5 on windows.

```
a = [[0]*10]*10
s = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        s = s + 1
        a[i][j] = s
        print(s,"",end="")
    print()
print("\n")

for i in range(10):
      for j in range(10):
            print(a[i][j],"", end="")
      print()
```

output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100


91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: The reasons are described in the linked post. The solution for your example is to replace the first line with: `a = [[0]*10 for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: thanks. Very helpful. I understood now